# Mixin for similar Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mixins

I'm not quite a Rails novice, but I'm certainly a long way from being an expert. I understand how modules work in a general sense, but I've never quite understood how I can use my own self-created modules to my advantage. This is a pretty simple example where I'm pretty sure a mixin module would be appropriate and useful.

My Rails application models association football (soccer) matches. Matches are represented by a `Match` model. I have several more models to represent events which might occur during a match (e.g. `Goal`, `PenaltyKick`, `Caution`). The `Match` model and the models for these events have a `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship.

Each of these models has three temporal attributes in common: `period`, `minute`, and `order_within_minute`. With the information in these columns, I can write a pretty simple `<=>` method to make these events comparable based on when they happen. It is crucial that I be able to compare the events on this basis so that I can return a sorted list of events within a match.

I understand that each of these models needs to include identical code in order to achieve what I want:

```
include Comparable

def <=>
  ## Comparison code goes here ##
end
```

It would seem to me that this can be accomplished with a mixin to apply that same bit of code to each of these models, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

I realize this is probably a really basic question, but what's the right way to do this? Do I put the above block of code within a module and `include` that module in each of these models, or do I need to do something different? Where do I put this code within my file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I put the above block of code within a module and include that module in each of these models, or do I need to do something different?

That's exactly what you do.

> Where do I put this code within my file system?

It should be fine living under `comparable.rb` in `app/models/concerns`, even though it doesn't make use of the syntactic sugar that `ActiveSupport::Concern` offers.

Comment: Am I also able to include other model-defining pieces of code in my mixin that these models would have in common? Things like `validates_presence_of :match`?

Comment: Sure would be able to! ActiveSupport::Concern provides an elegant DSL for that, which I would recommend using to provide these class methods.